# How can I select a random option?

Tags: c#, arrays, int

I have an array of ints, that It should like the following:

```
          7 3 2 4 5 6 1 9 10 8   Values
         [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]  Order In Array
```

This values should change its order, and every value, it's a random option, for example:

If it chooses that the first value is 6, it chooses the color blue, then, it goes to the second value, if the value is 4, it chooses green.

Every number is equal to a color.

I've been thinking that I can use an if conditional, but I dont know if there's a property to check the value, because if I do a if conditional for each option, it could take like 100+ lines of code!.
Do you have any idea of how can I improve it?.

Comment: look at a Dictionary<int, whatever> lookup

Comment: @Kenny if the lookup value is fixed then dictionary would be an overkill since array will work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this almost in one line :

```
var rnd = new Random();
var orderedNumbers = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
var randomizedNumbers = orderedNumbers.OrderBy(c => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Enumerable.Range(1, 10).OrderBy(c => rnd.Next()).ToArray();

Comment: Yep I almost posted this solution, but it only works if his first array is a regular sequence but didn't works if the ordered array is let's say 1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 15, etc.

Comment: My answer works in both cases, simply replace my orderedNumbers array with yours (ordered or not, regular or not) and it will be randomized